# Factorize RSA knowing several N and E

Tags: rsa

I did a CRT challenge yesterday and there`s one problem I was unable to solve, probably due to my lack of understanding advanced crypto math.

It`s about RSA. There are ten given pairs of N and E (modulo and exponent). E is always the standard exponent 10001 (hex). N is a 2048 bit number.

The task: factorize all N.

Well, I tried everything known to me (CRT, Wiener, p-1), no luck. Now it occurred to me that maybe 10 pairs aren't given to keep you busy but that maybe the vulnerability is located there?

Any ideas?

no, I don't have the data anymore. :)

Comment: Did they publish an exponent pair (e,d)?

Comment: i dont think so, only N and E like this:

10001 <...N1...>
10001 <...N2...>
10001 <...N3...>

Comment: There is no solution to the problem as you describe it. Perhaps some of the moduli were badly created and contain common factors.

Comment: Yeah, like CodesInChaos I would have tried gcd on the modulis...

Comment: possible. I asked the host for the numbers again, he ll send them to me, but i am not supposed to share them in public as they are being reused.

Anyways, how would the gcd() of two moduli help me?

Comment: alroight, i got the numbers.

So i did gcd(n1,n2) and got some huge number R, not 1. Is that a good thing?
i did n1 / R and got some result R2.
Checked R*R2 == n1 and yes, that`s the case. <is that a good thing? Would i not have to check for R and R2 being primes? which would take ages, as these are 2048 bit exponents...

Comment: @Ionelysis: The gcd of two integers is always a factor of those. So if it is not 1 (and the integers are not identical), you got a factor, and can now calculate other factors. This will only work if those numbers were generated by a bad RNG, though.

Comment: Could you add an answer what you did here? (We like answered questions.)

Comment: i hit enter accidentally, this isnt solved. I meant to say "i got the numbers used in the contest" ;)

edited above post.

Comment: Verifying if a number is prime can be done efficiently using a probabilistic algorithm, for example by checking if $a^p=a \pmod p$ for some different $a$s. (I believe there are also deterministic algorithms, but that's more complicated and doesn't gain anything in practice)

Comment: For the deterministic algorithm, see $\:$ www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/aks041411.pdf . $\hspace{.7 in}$

Comment: Why do you care if the factors are prime? RSA is always done using a product of two (probable) primes, so any nontrivial factor will be prime.

Comment: There's a good piece of software at factorable.net that can compute the GCD of several couples of integers at the same time

Comment: in a solvable math challenge, there has to be some trick for all the numbers you are given. And since you already figured out that two numbers share one prime, the rest should be straight forward. No need for some fancy library or program, your common math library for large integers should have the $gcd$ functionality built in and you don't need to test a lot of numbers. Worst case should be 25 gcd, 10 divisions and 15 primality tests. (Asumming they are in fact RSA numbers)

Comment: @Antimony While RSA moduli *usually* have two prime factors, that's not always the case. Using more factors improves the CRT speedup, but you need to be careful that the factors remain big enough so that elliptic curve factorization (whose cost depends on the size of the factors) is more expensive than GNFS (whose cost depends on the size of the modulus).

Answer (score 1):

If the moduli share no commonness / weak properties, it's impossible to solve the problem as given at hand. (As CodesInChaos pointed out)

Now as you're given RSA moduli, which are always constructed as $n=pq$, you can be sure that if you find $gcd(n_1,n_2)=R>1$, than either $R=p$ or $R=q$ must hold.
As you pointed out in the comments you indeed found such an $R_1$ for $n_1,n_2$. Now you reconstruct $P_1=n/R_1$ and check if $P_1*R_1=n$ holds, which is the case.
In the next step you check wether $P_1$ or $R_1$ divide any of the other moduli.
If it does, you reconstruct the other prime of these moduli via $n/R_1$. You repeat this procedure for all factors you're given.
As soon as you've done this step and still have unfactored moduli left, you try to apply the GCD on all pairs of unfactored moduli and use the resulting factors to obtain the remaing factors and factor the remaining moduli.